# Isolating a substring of a string in shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I'm using lynis to audit some AMI's that I'll be using. After lynis has run it writes to /var/log/lynis.log and gives a "Hardening Index" score to assess the overall hardening of the ami.

I get this value by running `sudo cat /var/log/lynis.log | grep "Hardening Index"`

Which in turn gives me this line:

```
2017-07-20 10:45:10 Hardening index : [58] [###########         ]
```

My question is how do I isolate the 58 to be assigned to a variable for an if statement comparison. I was thinking of using sed or regex but as this value will differ dependent on the ami, and could range from 0-100 I can't think of a way of just extracting that value. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `grep -oP 'Hardening Index\b.*\[\K\d+' path.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` and even skip your `grep` and `cat` like this:

```
awk -F '[][]+' '/Hardening [Ii]ndex/{print $2}' var/log/lynis.log
58
```

This `awk` uses `[` or `]` as field separator and extract 2nd field for record that matches `Hardening [Ii]ndex` regex.

To store this in a variable:

```
var=$(awk -F '[][]+' '/Hardening [Ii]ndex/{print $2}' var/log/lynis.log)
```

Comment: This work fantastically! I'm unfamiliar with the awk command. Could you explain a little more how -F '[][]+ ' separates/parses the string for the regex check?

Comment: `-F '[][]+ '` uses a bracket expression to set field separator as one or more of `[` or `]` characters.

Answer (score 2):

The computationally cheapest way to do that in a shell is to use the [POSIX parameter expansion facilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) (scroll to the bottom of the section) to avoid spawning external processes:

```
$ var='2017-07-20 10:45:10 Hardening index : [58] [###########         ]'
$ var=${var%%\]*} #remove longest endstring starting with ] 
$ var=${var##*\[} #remove longest startstring ending with [
$ echo $var
  58
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
sudo cat /var/log/lynis.log | grep "Hardening Index" | sed -r "s/.*?\[([0-9]+)\].*/\1/"
```

Answer (score 0):

try following awk too once.

```
awk '{match($0,/Harden[Ii]ng index.[^\]]*/);print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH-2,2)}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo cat /var/log/lynis.log | grep "Hardening [Ii]ndex"|sed -r 's/[^[]*\[([^]]*).*/\1/'
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.